# Client object has no attribute "load_extension"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

started a new discordpy program for the first time in a while, and was setting up cogs when this error was thrown:

[image]

here's the bit of code responsible:

[image]

I'm almost positive that I've used this code in an older program and yet it refuses to work. the online docs proved unhelpful, so here i am.

I won't embed it here, but if anyone wants, [here's my full program: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Ddl.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Ddl.png)

edit: (ignore line numbers not lining up, I've removed some unrelated code in the screenshot)

edit 2: (also I'm 100% sure that wasn't the code causing the error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `discord.Client` indeed has no attribute `load_extension`. You might confuse it for `commands.Bot`, which does have it.

If you define your `client` as `commands.Bot`, it should work.

```py
from discord import commands

client = commands.Bot()
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=load%20extension#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension